# Перегрузка оператора== не имеет доступа к приватному полям

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
bool operator== (book a, book b) {
    if (a.code == b.code) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

Перегрузка должна сравнивать объекты по одному полю, но поле закрыто для неё.

Comment: Ну так откройте.

Comment: сделайте оператор членом класса.  К закрытым полям имеют доступ только члены класса и его друзья

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот оператор нужно объявить дружественным к данному классу `book`.

```
class book {

// ..

friend bool operator == (book a, book b) ;

// ..

} ;
```